# Hatch which are created in Autodesk drawing file are showing in auto desk viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have created on dwg file containing hatch which is showing on the Autodesk desk top application.

But when I uploads this file to Autodesk Online viewer its shows only borders not the complete hatch.

[Autodesk Desktop Application DWG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AboI1.png)

[Autodesk Viewer Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lX3l.png)

In Autodesk viewer DWG must come with hatch

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots.  It could be a hatch pattern we missed (unlikely).  Can you tell me the hatch pattern style, or provide a test file, so we can try it out, on our end, and check for regressions  ? cheers

Comment: Pattern is solid.

Comment: https://www.bibliocad.com/en/library/mall_71070/